# How to Update UI inside volley response listener ? is runOnUiThread needed? or does Onresponse takes the control to UI Thread by itself?

Tags: android, android-volley, android-runonuithread

while using volley library ,if i want to update the listview adapter inside Response listener , should it be done using runOnUiThread? or is it already in UiThread?

Comment: i have tried both with and without runOnUiThread , but i am not sure if its needed or not .

Comment: What? if it works without it, then you don't need it. I don't follow you

Comment: sometimes i get this exception  android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.  but sometimes it works fine. thats why i asked this question

Comment: Why downvoting? That is a totally legit question: volley says it runs its callbacks in UI thread but without explicit switch to it you get an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the following exception when the adapter tries to modify view objects:

> android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

So, just do the following to be on the safe side:

```
geyActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes this is why i had this question, and i use runOnUiThread() as you suggested.. but onResponse takes the control back to UI thread , then why does this exception arise, and why is it we have to use runOnUiThread even when we are on UiThread?

Answer (score 0):

call handler from volley response

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
     Log.d("Response is: ", response);
     rui = response; // i put response to public String variable rui
     myHandler.post(updateRunnable);
     parseJSON(response);
}
```

and in onCreate Activity

```
myHandler = new Handler();

updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       //call the activity method that updates the UI
       updateUI();
    }
};
```

and your update on updateUI

```
public void updateUI(){
    t.setText(rui);
}
```

and make sure your id of widget is really existed.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/konten"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: `onResponse` runs on the `UIThread` so it is not necessary to use a handler.

Comment: my bad.. yes it works directly. so in my case the problem is because id is not well defined so it's always throw nullPoint exception.